# Integer overflow in enum when in template class

Tags: c++, templates, enums, metaprogramming

Digging into template metaprogramming I found a strange behaviour with range of enums in C++. I get a *warning: integer overflow in expression*, when it looks like I actually don't want a value that is out of range of enum. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template <int i>
class pow {
public:
        enum { result = 2*pow<i-1>::result};
};

template<>
class pow<0> {
public:
        enum { result = 1};
};

enum test { one, max = 4294967295 };
enum test_2 { last = 4294967295*2 };

int main() {
        std::cout << "pow<2>: \t" << pow<2>::result << std::endl;
        std::cout << "pow<4>: \t" << pow<4>::result << std::endl;
        std::cout << "pow<30>: \t" << pow<30>::result << std::endl;
        std::cout << "pow<31>: \t" << pow<31>::result << std::endl;
        std::cout << "max test: \t" << 
                std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type<test>::type>::max() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "max test_2: \t" << 
                std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type<test_2>::type>::max() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Compilation output:

```
test.cpp:7:19: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
  enum { result = 2*pow<i-1>::result};
                   ^
test.cpp:7:7: warning: overflow in constant expression [-fpermissive]
  enum { result = 2*pow<i-1>::result};
```

Program output:

```
pow<2>:         4
pow<4>:         16
pow<30>:        1073741824
pow<31>:        -2147483648
max test:       4294967295
max test_2:     18446744073709551615
```

Why enum in class pow have a smaller range? As far as I understand, for every 'i' value I have a different class instantiated, so it has got a separate enum type in it. In consequence, for 'i' > 31, enum should be 64 bit, like test_2 is. Where I am wrong?
I tried gcc 4.8 and gcc 5.4 and the results are the same.

Comment: If you are using C++11, you can use a `static constexpr` variable instead of your `enum`, or specify the enumeration type like so : `enum : long int {...};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

> **Unscoped enumeration**
>   `enum name { enumerator = constexpr , enumerator = constexpr , ... }`(1)
>   (...)
>   1) Declares an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed (in this case, the underlying type is **either int or, if not all enumerator values can be represented as int, an implementation-defined larger integral type that can represent all enumerator values**. If the enumerator-list is empty, the underlying type is as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0).

So in the template one your compiler seems to choose int, with a max value of +-2147483648 (31 bit + 1 for sign). In `test` the compiler seemed to recognize that this is not sufficient and choose `unsigned int` with a max value of 4294967296 (32 bit). In `test _2` the compiler recognized this is also not sufficient and choose a unsigned type with 64 bit (max 18446744073709551616).

Declaring your enum as

```
enum { result = 2*pow<i-1>::result, randomMax = \*insert anything large here*\};
```

should do the trick. The second value only has to force the compiler to choose a type that is long enough to hold all the values you need.

Comment: First: `template <long int i>` is a better option for large numbers. Second: think about types in `result = pow<i-1>::result*2`. _pow<0>::result_ is an int, multiplied by 2 gives int, so pow<1>::result is an int, and that pattern is repeated. There is no way to change the type in recursion in that way (because enum has a concrete type, which I was no aware of). `enum { result = 2l*pow<i-1>::result }` is enough to make this work, because the multiplication gives long type, and then the compiler decides what type to use for _result_.